# Four Dimensional Integration Bounds

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I'm trying to integrate a function over the space where this polynomial is positive:

$(a^2 + b^2) (c^2 + d^2) - (ac + bd + T)^2 \geq 0 $, where $a,b,c,d$ are variables and $T$ is some constant. I've been able to get the inequality into terms of one variable, but it's unclear where to go from here. How do I translate this space into bounds for integration?